# Confused about UITextView, UIButton and BOOL

Tags: ios, uitextview, 32bit-64bit

I have a textView and a button. Button's `enabled` property is related to length of text in textView. I assign NSUInteger to BOOL directly which is proved to be unsuitable now.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.button.enabled = textView.text.length; //unsuitable on 32-bit. Should be `textView.text.length > 0`
}
```

The strange thing on 32-bit devices : If I paste "abc" into textView, or paste "ab" then type "c", the button is always disabled. But if I type these three letters one by one, the button performs as it should be. All of the 3 situations reach self.button.enabled = (BOOL)3, but why the performance of button is different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Type of BOOL**

The differing behaviour is actually linked to the device's architecture. There's a difference on how the iOS SDK defines a BOOL for 32 versus 64 bit architectures. See this excerpt from `objc.h`:

```
#if !defined(OBJC_HIDE_64) && TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __LP64__
typedef bool BOOL;
#else
typedef signed char BOOL; 
#endif
```

So `BOOL` on 32 bit can have any value between 0 and 255, while on 64 bit it is compiler enforced to only have the values 0 or 1. You can easily try this by running the following line on the simulator, set to iPhone 4s (32 bit) or iPhone 6 (64 bit).

```
NSLog(@"%d", (BOOL)2);
```

That is why you see differing behavior on different devices.

**EDIT :** Post OP comment:

Well to understand that, you need to see how `enabled` property is laid down : `unsigned int enabled:1`. This defines the bit-field of width one.

On `32 bit` systems, per C standards, when assigning an unsigned integer of greater width the remaining bits are just dropped. So the lowest bit is what actually drives the enabling/disabling of button.

Comment: This should be selected answer. Absolutely correct.

Comment: @Abhinav Thank you for answer but you may not seize the key of my question. For example, the string is "abc". On 32-bit, if I paste "abc" into textView, or paste "ab" then type "c", the button is always disabled. But if I type these letters one by one, the button performs as it should be. All of the 3 situations reach `self.button.enabled = (BOOL)3`, right?

Comment: Please take a look at my updated post. All your three cases lies into lowest bit read which is 1  for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers.

Comment: And where you find this `unsigned int enabled:1` :)

Comment: Well, this is binary world! Under the hood everything is laid down in bits 0/1 - even your strings. I believe the bits picked in 32 bit system for your string is turned out to be 0.

Comment: Oh sorry, the question in my last reply is wrong and I have deleted it. I mean the length of "abc" is 3, you said "lowest bit read 1 for odd numbers", does it mean button.enabled = 1 = YES? In fact, the button is unavailable..

Comment: Nope - length is out of question here. Its about how "abc" is laid down in memory like 1011011101101 as an example. Since BOOL would take only 1 byte (owing to declaration in 32 bit architecture), rest of the bits will be ignored. Character made from those taken bits would deduce the enabling/disabling of button. Hope this makes sense!